# How to implement facebook api conversions with nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I made a website for a client, using nextjs 13, and he wants to advertise on facebook ads, but for that we need to use the facebook pixel and the conversions API to collect user data. I implemented the pixel following the example of the vercel repository. But I haven't found an easy way to implement Facebook API conversions. I used the following [@rivercode/facebook-conversion-api-nextjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rivercode/facebook-conversion-api-nextjs) package following the instructions in the documentation, but I'm not sure it's working, it doesn't seem to be.

There's any easy way implement it in next or maybe some integration in vercel deployment??

Comment: Yes, but the only way I found to do this was using Google Tag Manager to manage the Facebook API. I used this video as a reference: youtu.be/pd7P60Hzsyk?si=BsnBWuJF2LdS6bG2 [It's in Portuguese, but maybe you can use automatic subtitles]

An english content: https://youtu.be/L65roS_B4rA?si=ZexiZ2w9g9ln-9LV
[But it's a little different from the first video]